# Wagtail - How to set rich text value in nested block (StreamField->StructBlock->RichTextBlock)

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have the following structure:

```
`class ParagraphWithRelatedLinkBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    text = blocks.RichTextBlock()
    related_link = blocks.ListBlock(blocks.URLBlock())

class BlogPageSF(Page):
    body = StreamField(
        [
            ("paragraph", ParagraphWithRelatedLinkBlock(),
        ], use_json_field=True
)`
```

I want to set value of 'text' field from script or Django shell (not via the Wagtail admin site).

How can I do that?

I have tried to do the following in shell:

```
`p = BlogPageSF()
rt = RichTextBlock('Test')
pb = ParagraphWithRelatedLinkBlock()
pb.text = rt
p.body.append(('paragraph', pb))
p.save()`
```

I expect that 'text' field in ParagraphWithRelatedLinkBlock will have value of 'Test'

But I get error:
AttributeError: 'ParagraphWithRelatedLinkBlock' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you insert into StreamField data should *not* be instances of the Block class - block instances are only used as part of the stream definition (for example, when you write `text = blocks.RichTextBlock()`, you're creating an instance of RichTextBlock that forms part of the `ParagraphWithRelatedLinkBlock` definition).

The correct data types are either simple Python values, such as `dict` for a StructBlock, or a dedicated value type such as `wagtail.rich_text.RichText` for a RichTextBlock. So, in the case of ParagraphWithRelatedLinkBlock, you need to supply a dict containing a RichText value:

```
from wagtail.rich_text import RichText

p = BlogPageSF()
p.body.append(('paragraph', {'text': RichText('Test')}))
p.save()
```

Comment: This isn't working for me for some reason.
It complains about `TypeError: Object of type RichText is not JSON serializable`